# Use an imported schema in my main schema with correct namespaces

Tags: import, xsd, namespaces

I have a schema with a namespace 'http://myobjects' which I am importing to my main schema like that:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://services">
<import schemaLocation="myobjects.xsd" namespace="http://myobjects" />
<element name="registerClaim">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Claims">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Claim" xmlns:mo="http://myobjects" type="mo:Claim" />
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

Now, when I create a sample XML based on this schema, element 'Claim' is in 'http://services' namespace as expected and all of it's children are in '' namespace so it no longer validates with myobjects.xsd schema.

```
  <ser:registerClaim xmlns:ser="http://services">
     <ser:Claims>
        <ser:Claim>
           <documentData>
              <policyData>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to modify my main XSD so the resulting XML would like like this:

```
  <ser:registerClaim xmlns:ser="http://services" xmlns:mo="http://mybojects">
     <ser:Claims>
        <ser:Claim>
           <mo:documentData>
              <mo:policyData>
```

or like this:

```
  <ser:registerClaim xmlns:ser="http://services">
     <ser:Claims>
        <ser:Claim xmlns="http://myobjects">
           <documentData>
              <policyData>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please can you share the contents of myobjects.xsd. I suspect I know what the problem is.

Comment: elementFormDefault="qualified" ? :)